# SQL Server 2008 - Need to report on a value within an XML column based on another XML Value

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xpath

I have a column that stores `XML` data. Inside this data, I need to report on one field when another `field = xxxx`.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SourceIdentifierPairs xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas">
  <SourceIdentifierPair>
    <Source>ABCPN</Source>
    <Identifier>123456789</Identifier>
  </SourceIdentifierPair>
  <SourceIdentifierPair>
    <Source>ABCMR</Source>
    <Identifier>000000123654</Identifier>
  </SourceIdentifierPair>
    <SourceIdentifierPair>
    <Source>PRIM</Source>
    <Identifier>00112233</Identifier>
  </SourceIdentifierPair>
</SourceIdentifierPairs>
```

When the source is `ABCPN` I need to pull the `Identifier`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XPath expression you're looking for is

```
//SourceIdentifierPair[Source='ABCPN']/Identifier
```

Make sure to register the default namespace.

**Sample Code:**

```
declare @x xml = '<SourceIdentifierPairs xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas">
  <SourceIdentifierPair>
    <Source>ABCPN</Source>
    <Identifier>123456789</Identifier>
  </SourceIdentifierPair>
  <SourceIdentifierPair>
    <Source>ABCMR</Source>
    <Identifier>000000123654</Identifier>
  </SourceIdentifierPair>
    <SourceIdentifierPair>
    <Source>PRIM</Source>
    <Identifier>00112233</Identifier>
  </SourceIdentifierPair>
</SourceIdentifierPairs>'

--xpath as above, with default namespace specified
;with xmlnamespaces ('http://schemas' as ns1, default 'http://schemas')
select @x.value('(//SourceIdentifierPair[Source=''ABCPN'']/Identifier)[1]', 'nvarchar(32)') IdentifierABCPN

--more complex version of the above code (may be useful should you have more complex requirements in future)
;with xmlnamespaces ('http://schemas' as ns1)
select @x.value('(/ns1:SourceIdentifierPairs/ns1:SourceIdentifierPair[./ns1:Source/text()[.=''ABCPN'']]/ns1:Identifier/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(32)') IdentifierABCPN
```

Comment: So I understand this, but the XML changes with with every message.  These are records coming in daily and I need to pull the ABCPN and report on it.